# Is there a "break" tag to escape a loop in Liquid?

Tags: liquid

How do I break out of loop in Liquid, mainly a for-loop? I've tried `{% break %}`, but that fails with *There were errors saving your file: Unknown tag 'break'*.

I'm trying to achieve something like:

```
var variants = [];
{% for item in cart.items %}
    {% if item.product.handle == "handle-name" %}
    variants = {{item.product.variants | json}};
    {% break %} // won't work
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

For future visitors. Above code **does** work in current Liquid (gem v2.5.1).

So, you can simply do:

```
{% for item in cart.items %}
    {% if item.product.handle == "handle-name" %}
    variants = {{item.product.variants | json}};
       {% break %} // This will work
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Joost is right. Simply update your liquid gem. Check out this page https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/issues/119

Comment: Odd, I somehow missed this answer. Thanks for the comment Hossain, I cannot test it but the answer seems correct so I am accepting it.

Comment: It works, but its still not part of the shopify docs - https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/tags/iteration-tags

Comment: Docs have been updated to include `{% break %}` and `{% continue %}`