# Jekyll break for loop

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm processing site.posts to compare post.categories against page.categories to create a related posts sidebar but if there are multiple common categories I get multiple links.

I want to break the inner loop but can't find anything to suggest this is possible.

Roughly (because on train and phone) the code I have is

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
      {% for postcat in post.categories %}
            {% for cat in page.categories %}
                  {% if cat == postcat %}
                        <p> {{ post.title }} </p>
                  {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Not sure this is even doable

Comment: i agree. this is a duplicate unless you are specifically asking how to do this with an older version.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is more of a `Liquid Templating engine` question, than a `Jekyll` one. It appears that `Liquid` has support for a `{% break %}` tag which is what you are looking for.

I would suggest making sure your `Liquid` gem is updated and then try using `{% break %}` in your code as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028229/is-there-a-break-tag-to-escape-a-loop-in-liquid).

[Possible Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028229/is-there-a-break-tag-to-escape-a-loop-in-liquid)